# Adding Slots to PHP Engine Template in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony

I'm having trouble adding slots...

I have the following in my base template:

```
 <?php $view['slots']->output('javascript', '') ?>
```

And in another template that extends that template I have:

```
<?php $view['slots']->start('javascript') ?>
<script type="text/babel" src="/src/react-nominate-request.js"></script>
<?php $view['slots']->stop() ?>
```

That script tag never appears.  I've read through the docs and don't see what I am missing any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how I am extending my templates:
I have a base template with doctype head, body and scripts used by entire app

I have a layout with the html structure for my app (header, footer, and margins) that extends the base template.

```
<?php $view->extend('::base.html.php') ?>
```

Each of the three pages in my application has page specific html (basically divs with IDs the react components reference) that extends the layout template
//page template

```
<?php $view->extend(':interface:layout.html.php') ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're extending correct template? Are you sure it's not connected with cache?

Comment: I'm using slots for title and content all of which are working as expected...

Comment: I have also cleared the cache and tested outputing the _content slot multiple times to ensure the template is rendering the latest changes.

Comment: What is Symfony version you are using?

Comment: Using Symfony 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the bright idea of changing the name of my slot to _scripts and that made it start working as expected....

Inside my base template:

```
<?php $view['slots']->output('_scripts') ?>
```